# Запустить остальную часть скрипта независимо от while

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, while

Я играюсь с консолью через `VS Code`. Я хочу заставить меняться название консоли во время работы программы через цикл `while`, но он выполняется а скрипт нет. Я понимаю что это (скорее всего) из-за того что он повторяется и не даёт другой части выполнится. Как мне заставить их работать одновременно в одном скрипте?
Скрипт:

```
from progress.bar import *
from time import sleep
from colorama import *
import os
import ctypes
import getpass
from random import randint
from art import tprint
just_fix_windows_console()

nameprogramm = 1

while nameprogramm == 1:
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(b"2643728")
    sleep(0.1)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(b"8756544")
    sleep(0.1)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(b"7786953")
    sleep(0.1)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleA(b"help")    
bar = ShadyBar(Fore.RED + 'Скоро начнём =)', max=200)
for i in range(200):
    bar.next()
    sleep(00.01)
    bar.finish()
os.system("cls")
sleep(1)
tprint("HELLO")
sleep(2)
os.system('cls')
tprint("Im Dahlian")
sleep(2)
tprint("Leave a programm..")
sleep(5)
tprint("Please")
 sleep(2)
input(Fore.RED + "Вы покинете программу? (да/нет):")
```